# Truffle work over HTTPS

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-migration, truffle-config

I installed my own ethereum node and put it behind HTTPS nginx proxy. `geth attach works perfectly` but `truffle deploy` failed with error:

```
<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor=\"white\">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1>
</center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>

<hr><center>nginx/1.10.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I understand why it happens, question is how to force Truffle work over HTTPS, not HTTP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found workaround for this case, just add `provider` field to `truffle.js`:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    ropsten: {
      .................
      provider: new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://host.name:8545')
    },
    rinkeby: {
      ......
      provider: new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://host.name:8546')
    }
  }
};
```